# Writing a C function to parse a Hex string and convert it to decimal?

Tags: c

I am just learning C and in my class this is a part of our first program.

The full description of the function I am trying to implement:

if that's tl;dr, a key point is that I am not allowed to use functions from other libraries (so something like `srtol` is ruled out).

> `int parseHexString(char *hexString, int *integerRead);`  The first
>   parameter is a null terminated C string, that represents a hexadecimal
>   integer. This function parses this string, accumulating the integer
>   value it represents. This integer value is placed at the location
>   pointed to by the second parameter, integerRead. If a bad hexadecimal
>   character, thus an invalid hex value, is encountered, this function
>   stops looking at further characters within the string and returns -1.
>   If a good hex value is parsed, it returns 0.
>
> The correct way to implement this function looks at the first
>   character within the string first and does not use a stack to
>   accomplish the parsing. Your first assembly language program will need
>   to implement what this function accomplishes, so you will save
>   yourself time by implementing this function the correct way.
>
> For this function, do not call any functions from any libraries; as an
>   exception, for debugging purposes only, you may use `printf()`. It will
>   help our grading if you remove your debugging code before you submit
>   your assignment.

I am NOT just looking for a full implementation of this function, just some tips or hints to get me started.

I feel as though there is some intuitive way of doing this, but right now I am blanking.  I'm concerned with how I am supposed to start at the first character of the string and then go forward from there to convert it to decimal.

Comment: Wow they even mention what functions you can use **before you send the homework**.

Comment: How many characters of hex does it take to make 1 byte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

- Get the length of the string
- Walk the string from left to right
- For each character:

  - Check if it's a valid hex character
  - Add its decimal value multiplied by 16^x, where x is the number of characters left on the right